# How to force cmake to use the new version of CMP0077 (allow options to be set from variables)

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to add Howard Hinnant's `date` library as a subdirectory of my build. Here's the simple setup:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date.git
$ cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(date_test)

set(BUILD_TZ_LIB ON)
set(USE_SYSTEM_TZ_DB ON)
set(ENABLE_DATE_TESTING OFF)
add_subdirectory(date)
```

Not much going on here. When I try to configure this build as-is, using cmake 3.18.3, I get a bunch of output like:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at date/CMakeLists.txt:30 (option):
  Policy CMP0077 is not set: option() honors normal variables.  Run "cmake
  --help-policy CMP0077" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
  set the policy and suppress this warning.

  For compatibility with older versions of CMake, option is clearing the
  normal variable 'USE_SYSTEM_TZ_DB'.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at date/CMakeLists.txt:34 (option):
  Policy CMP0077 is not set: option() honors normal variables.  Run "cmake
  --help-policy CMP0077" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
  set the policy and suppress this warning.

  For compatibility with older versions of CMake, option is clearing the
  normal variable 'ENABLE_DATE_TESTING'.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at date/CMakeLists.txt:37 (option):
  Policy CMP0077 is not set: option() honors normal variables.  Run "cmake
  --help-policy CMP0077" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
  set the policy and suppress this warning.

  For compatibility with older versions of CMake, option is clearing the
  normal variable 'BUILD_TZ_LIB'.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

# date: USE_SYSTEM_TZ_DB OFF
# date: MANUAL_TZ_DB OFF
# date: USE_TZ_DB_IN_DOT OFF
# date: BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF
# date: ENABLE_DATE_TESTING OFF
# date: DISABLE_STRING_VIEW OFF
```

Notably, my variables got ignored (`USE_SYSTEM_TZ_DB` is `OFF` when I want it to be `ON`).

If I do what the error says, and add `cmake_policy(SET CMP0077 NEW)`, then... I get the exact same thing. Same warning messages about the policy. Same ignoring of the variables I have set.

Is there a way to set these variables and have them propagate into the `date` build, or do I *have* to declare these as `CACHE INTERNAL` variables?

Comment: According to the docs, the [policy CMP0077](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0077.html) is introduces in CMake 3.13, so it should be enabled by default with any `cmake_minimum_required` call with VERSION 3.13 or more. It seems that your `date/CMakeLists.txt` specifies `cmake_minimum_required` with the lesser version. You need either to change that call to use newer version, or issue `cmake_policy(SET CMP0077 NEW)` after that call.

Comment: What would do `unset(BUILD_TZ_LIB) unset(BUILD_TZ_LIB CACHE)` and then `set` it?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't control `date` though, does that mean I'm out of luck?

Comment: date's [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) recommends using `FetchContent` to use the library. On another note, this seems interesting: `cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.7 )`: isn't 3.2 the latest cmake version available?

Comment: @Barry My bad. 3.2 < 3.7 < 3.20. I didn't see the 0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Setting the default value of that policy via `set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0077 NEW)` before the call to `add_subdirectory` that adds the date library to your project fixes the problem.

According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMPNNNN.html),

> Commands cmake_minimum_required(VERSION) and cmake_policy(VERSION) by default leave policies introduced after the given version unset. Set CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP to OLD or NEW to specify the default for policy CMP, where  is the policy number.

When `CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0077` is not set, the `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)` call in the `CMakeLists.txt` of the date-library resets the value of that policy to the OLD behavior. If CMake didn't do that the build of a sub-project included via `FetchContent` or git submodules could easily break if the parent project updates their CMakeLists.txt to require a newer version.

Comment: Huh. That... seems to work. I don't understand why, but I'm totally okay with that.

Comment: @Barry I've extended the answer to explain why this works where it didn't before.

Comment: Note that using `cmake_policy(CMP0077 NEW)` will not work in this case: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20312

Comment: @Eyjafl This is why this answer says to set CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0077, just as described in the issue you linked.

Comment: @Corristo Yeah, my comment had no intention of downplaying your answer, it's just an explicit note for others because for me personally this was not obvious